# How to access input device driver from userspace

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm currently developing an input subsystem driver for touchscreen. What I don't know is how to access the device from userspace, e.g. how to open a file that should be created in filesystem. 
What I've done so far is this:
After I *insmod* the driver, I get the following message in *dmesg*:

*input: driver_name as /devices/platform/soc/3f804000.i2c/i2c-1/1-0038/input/input0*

Now when I go at this location, I find *input0*, which is a directory. In this directory, I can find files such as *name*, *properties*, *uevent*, but none of the files here contains touch data.

My question here is, where does input subsystem puts touch data after I call

```
input_report_abs(data.input, ABS_X, coord_x);
input_report_abs(data.input, ABS_Y, coord_y);
input_sync(data.input);
```

Comment: Study **Documentation/input/input.rst** in your kernel source.

Comment: I've read all of the documentation about input subsystem, but none of the files in Documentation/input explains how to read from userspace.

Comment: *"none of the files in Documentation/input explains how to read from userspace"* -- If you actually studied **Documentation/input/input.rst**, then you would find that it describes all of the salient items that you mentioned such as **/dev/input/**, `eventX` devices,  the **evtest** program, and the `struct input_event`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:
Once you do *insmod*, new file is created under */dev/input*, in my case it was *event0* file. In order to test the functionality, you can do *evtest input0*. This file can be used from a userspace program in the following way:

```
struct input_event ev;
FILE* fd = open("/dev/input/event0", O_RDWR);
while(1)
{
    int count = read(fd, &ev, sizeof(struct input_event);
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)count / sizeof(struct input_event); i++)
    {
        if(EV_KEY == ev.type) // printf ...
        if(EV_ABS == ev.type) // printf ...
    }
}
```

Hope this will help somebody because I feel like this isn't covered enough in Documentation.